# The code will not run nor will it show an error message

Tags: python

The following code will not run nor will it show an error message. Please help. Also, how would I add a function to display only the output of this code?

```
def main():
 s= ""
 phrase=""
 programdescription(s)
 userinput(phrase)

 #This function displays the program description   
def programdescription(s):
 s = print("This program determines if a word, phrase, or sequence can be read the same backward as forward.")

#This function requests user input for analysis 
def userinput(phrase):
 phrase = input("Enter a word or phrase: ")


def s_phrase(phrase):
 phrase = phrase.upper()
 strippedPhrase = ""
 for char in phrase:
     if (48 <= ord(char) <= 57) or (65 <= ord(char) <= 90):
         strippedPhrase += char
         flag = True
     n = len(strippedPhrase)
     for j in range(int(n / 2)):
         if strippedPhrase[j] != strippedPhrase[n - j - 1]:
             flag = False
             break
     if flag:
         print(phrase, "is a palindrome.")
     else:
         print(phrase, "is not a palindrome.")


main()
```

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, please fix your example code so that someone can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Python. String reversal is as simple as `phrase[::-1]` - https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html.

Comment: On another note, you never call `s_phrase` anywhere, which may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @chrisz - That worked, thank you. It helps having more eyes.

Comment: I would recommend a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) as an extra set of eyes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem 1 is you never call s_phrase.
Problemo 2 is that the phrase variable can't be seen by s_phrase.
Problem numero C is that your indentation is messed up.
Issue 4 is more the fact that this seems like a very 'C' way of tackling the challenge. Borrowing from Spade, here is a more succinct way of doing it that is formatted to your original program.

```
def main():
    s= ""
    phrase=""
    programdescription(s)
    s_phrase(phrase)

 #This function displays the program description   
def programdescription(s):
    s = print("This program determines if a word, phrase, or sequence can be read the same backward as forward.")

#This function requests user input for analysis 


def s_phrase(phrase):
    phrase = input("Enter a word or phrase: ")
    phrase = phrase.upper()
    r_phrase = phrase[::-1]
    print(r_phrase)
    if phrase == r_phrase:
        print(phrase, "is a palindrome.")
    else:
        print(phrase, "is not a palindrome.")


main()
```